# How to disable Babel in Kibana for plugin development

Tags: kibana

When developing a plugin for Kibana, `npm start` automatically transforms plugin code using Babel.  Is there a way to disable that to simplify local debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/tasks/config/babel.js` and add a line under `src` to exclude your plugin code.